# Chart web part with Hyperlink Field Incorrectly

Tags: chart-web-part

I created chart web part with hyperlink field based on title of the list item but when clicking a bar on the chart sends me to master page url

```
http://domainname/_catalogs/masterpage/ListItemTitle
```

Does any one know when i clicking a bar to redirect to correct list item?

Comment: Anyone found an answer to this one yet?